# Prompting the user to load multiple RData

Tags: r, storage

I am trying to prompt the user to load multiple ".RData" files using the following code:

```
flist <- choose.files()
```

After selecting the files, `flist` looks like:

```
[1] "C:\\Users\\M\\Desktop\\New.Data\\Ford.Iregs.RData"
[2] "C:\\Users\\M\\Desktop\\New.Data\\GL.Iregs.RData"
```

Then, I try to load the data using:

```
dt <- lapply(flist, load,.GlobalEnv)
```

However, I don't get the contents of the two ".RData" files in return (which are two data frames), but I get two characters with the file names:

```
dt
[[1]]
[1] "Ford.Iregs"
[[2]]
[1] "GL.Iregs"
```

I tried using `tk_choose.files()` as well, but the same result.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You might not need to make an assignment statement (i.e. `dt <- `).  When loading an .Rdata file, just a `load(file="asdf.Rdata")` statement often suffices.  Not sure if this behavior will hold when inside an `lapply()`, but it might be worth a shot.

Comment: @MattTyers Thanks for the tip, but this is not the issue.

Comment: how about a duct tapey `for(i in 1:length(flist)) load(flist[i])`?

Comment: @MattTyers yes this works but I was hopping to find a way to avoid for loop. Thanks anyways